# When is the right time to get final executable of spawned process created by Twisted spawnProcess?

Tags: twisted

I'm trying to start a process with twisted spawnProcess, and use psutil to record resource usage every 5 seconds. First, I try to get the executable name of the spawned process with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import protocol
import psutil


class MyPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade!"
        process = psutil.Process(self.transport.pid)
        print process.pid, process.exe
    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "out", data,
    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "error", data,
    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited"
    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "processEnded"
        print "quitting"

pp = MyPP()

reactor.spawnProcess(pp, 'cat', ['cat'])

reactor.run()
```

I expect to get "xxxx /bin/cat", but I got the following instead:

```
connectionMade!
31293 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

I use ps to check it, the pid is right, but executable is wrong

```
ming.dai 31293  0.0  0.0   4328   356 pts/6    S+   10:30   0:00 cat
```

Could someone tell me the right way or right time to get executable of the spawn process?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Given that

- `psutil` reads the process information from `proc`
- and `spawnProcess` uses `os.execvp` which replaces the current process (`python`) with the new one (in this case `cat`)
- and you request the process information almost immediately

it seems the system does not update fast enough the `/proc/<pid>` entry with the new process information.

You can confirm this by adding a small delay:

```
    import time; time.sleep(.1)
    print process.pid, process.exe
```

and you will see the expected output `<pid> /bin/cat`.

If you don't need the process executable right away it will work as expected, otherwise you will need to add a little delay to give time to the system to update the `/proc` entry.

Comment: Actually, the system may be updating "immediately" when the change is made, but it doesn't matter.  The problem is that connectionMade is called when the ProcessProtocol first gets a handle to the pipes pointing at the subprocess - which is immediately after the `fork()` call.  There's no event that can be hooked in the parent process for detecting the `exec()` call, so Twisted doesn't provide one.  Of course if someone knows a way to prove me wrong about this, please file a bug :).

Comment: Thanks @Glyph for clarifying what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than waiting for your process to be spawned and determine executable later, you can use [`procutils.which`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.procutils.which.html) to get an absolute path first, and perhaps call [`os.path.realpath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) on the result if you really really want to know where the binary image lives.

(As I pointed out in my comment in the other answer, it's not possible, in a portable, general way, to determine when the subprocess has actually `exec`'d.)